# Need to access the username in a function

Tags: python, html, django, function

I am using the django web framework and need to access a username in a function in my views.py. I need it just to assign a class dependent on whether the data belongs to the user, or someone else.

So the request view is separate, the view in question is just for rendering the calendar. As follows:

```
@login_required
def holiday(request):
    #i want this later on
    user = request.user

    #some stuff to make the calendar
    cal = HolidayCalendar(my_holidays).formatmonth(year, month)

    # more stuff 

    context = {
        "calendar": mark_safe(cal),
    }
    return render(request, "tande/calendar.html", context)
```

And here is the HTML calendar that I need to access the user in

```
class HolidayCalendar(HTMLCalendar):

    def __init__(self, holiday):
        super(HolidayCalendar, self).__init__()
        self.holiday = self.holiday_days(holiday)

    def formatday(self, day, weekday, user):
        #do some stuff...
        if holiday_object:
            # links to holiday object
            body.append('<a href="%s"><center>' % holiday_object.get_absolute_url())
            body.append(esc(holiday_object.person_id))
            body.append('</center></a>')

            # I NEED THE USER HERE
            if holiday_object.person_id == user:
                body.append('<hr class="holiday">')
            else:
                #want to have a different hr class
```

And I don't know how to pass the user to this function.... I tried sessions but that also didn't work without a request.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing is just to pass the user to the class initialiser.

```
def __init__(self, holiday, user):
    super(HolidayCalendar, self).__init__()
    self.user = user
    self.holiday = self.holiday_days(holiday)

def formatday(self, day, weekday):
    ...
    if holiday_object.person_id == self.user:
```

and in your view:

```
cal = HolidayCalendar(my_holidays, request.user).formatmonth(year, month)
```

Comment: How do I then use this in my format_day ? I need to see if the person_id of the Holiday object = user

Comment: Isn't that what I show in the last line of the first snippet?

Comment: Ah yes I forgot to use self.user I was just using user! Thank you!